# Distributing tasks between multiprocessing workers

Tags: python, concurrency, python-multiprocessing

In the book "Mastering Concurrency in Python", chapter 6 "Working with Processes in Python": "Message passing between several workers", example 7, there is implementation of task queue. Here is its code: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-Concurrency-in-Python/blob/master/Chapter06/example7.py

The author states the problem with this example:

> Everything seems to be working, but if we look closely at the messages our processes have printed out, we will notice that most of the tasks were executed by either Consumer-2 or Consumer-3, and that Consumer-4 executed only one task while Consumer-1 failed to execute any. What happened here?

I tried to understand the explanation of the problem that author gives and it looks like it is wrong:

> Essentially, when one of our consumers—let's say Consumer-3—finished executing a task,
> it tried to look for another task to execute immediately after. Most of the time, it would get priority over other consumers, since it was already being run by the main program. So
> while Consumer-2 and Consumer-3 were constantly finishing their tasks' executions and
> picking up other tasks to execute, Consumer-4 was only able to "squeeze" itself in once,
> and Consumer-1 failed to do this altogether.

> To address this issue, a technique has been developed, to stop consumers from immediately taking the next item from the task queue, called poison pill. The idea is that, after setting up the real tasks in the task queue, we also add in dummy tasks that contain "stop" values
> and that will have the current consumer hold and allow other consumers to get the next
> item in the task queue first; hence the name "poison pill."

The problem seems different: as consumers are started before queue is filled with tasks, most of consumers exit without processing queue, because they find it empty [here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-Concurrency-in-Python/blob/master/Chapter06/example7.py#L16). Adding poison pills helps because it eliminates the race between empty() and get() calls - and not because it lowers priority of consumers. Poison pills are not in effect before queue has no more tasks, that is why poison pills cannot influence which consumer will take the task.

Moreover, it seems to be a bug in this example: if other consumer steals task from the queue between our consumer calls to empty() and get(), then our consumer will block indefinitely on get(), which actually happens on my laptop.

Who can validate please.

Comment: Your observed 'different' problem is spot on. Using `queue.empty()` checks for control-flow is an anti-pattern for precisely the reasons you mentioned. Usage of poison pills _instead_ is the remedy. After taking one, a worker should stop participating or it was not poison. Poison pills don't "lower(s) priority of consumers" hence is correct. Alone they are not sufficient to provide the kind of fine grained coordination the author seems to suggest.

Comment: Note that the behavior the author describes as issue, isn't a problem per se.
Enforcing participation of all workers for all workloads isn't something which will result in guaranteed performance gains. More likely than not, 'enforcing' instead of merely 'enabling' having all workers employment, will slow things down due to increased overhead.

Comment: Generally, I find the use of "poisoned pills" to be difficult for anything other than trivial systems. It's mixing "data plane" and "control plane" traffic into a single queue. When building a more complex distributed system, where a process might well be receiving input from more than 1 queue, one ends up with a reactor (like select() or epoll() in C), and then the question "who sends the poisoned pill?" becomes more difficult. So I often end up with a queue for sending commands to processes, as well as queues carrying data to/from processes. ZMQ starts becoming very useful for this.